# trying to avoid hard coding markup in react given but unsure if it is efficient

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, to avoid hardcoding here:

```
photos.map((photo, i) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {
        Object.keys(photo).map(j =>
          <td>
            {photo[j]}
          </td>
        )
      }
    </tr>
  );
});
```

Obviously this is better than hard coding each column, but is this efficient?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The first map should be below the return.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is good. You can refactor your two maps into separate methods, but that depends.

Here is an [example from React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component), they show how to use the map for dynamic items.

> Tip: You will want to add `keys` to your `<tr>` and `<td>`

I hope that helps!